# Is there any way to update any particular file in already uploaded application in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

We have a project service uploaded in GAE. It is working fine but some time we need to change message string in ini/properties or change any particular image file for that we redeploy the whole application every time.

So as a user point of view. I think there should be a vision to upload a particular component/file from GAE interface.

Comment: If you have resources such as config/images etc  that changed a lot then consider storing them in the GCS or the datastore.  However this route may mean loss of change control, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Use datastore/memcache.

There are no way to update particular file without re-deploying all application files.

Comment: Use datastore/memcache?

Comment: Yeah. Use datastore to keep your ini/properties/images dynamic.

Comment: Yeah. I ended up doing that too, it was the best way after trying alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW the entire application does not redeploy every time. The appcfg.py tool is smart enough to work out only the files that have changed and push them up, not the entire thing.

Now the problem you might face is that when you redeploy your app, it will result in new instances being started to load the updated files and if you had a lot of in memory state you'd lose it.